# How can I select target within inventory?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like to know how to target a playbook on a specific hosts within the inventory file with a specific column...

My inventory file:

```ini
[server]
demo_1.example.com dc="pri"
demo_2.example.com dc="sec"
demo_3.example.com dc="pri"
```

I want just run a playbook over the servers with dc="pri"
What is should be the syntax ?
`ansible-playbook -i inventory/my_file role/my_playbook.yaml`

Answer (score 2):

You are taking the problem upside down in my opinion. With what you ask, you basically want to define a group based on an individual variable defined for each host. This is possible but really not ideal.

Instead of that, create the needed groups and assign the variables to the group. Here is an example for the above in a all in one ini inventory

```ini
[server:children]
primary
secondary

[primary]
demo_1.example.com
demo_3.example.com

[primary:vars]
dc="pri"

[secondary]
demo_2.example.com

[secondary:vars]
dc="sec"
```

You can then target for example in your `hosts` play target or as a `--limit` to the ansible command line:

- all servers: `server`
- only the primary dc: `primary`

---

Now if for any reason you need to keep your original inventory untouched, you can still achieve something similar to above with a [constructed dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/constructed_inventory.html)

`inventory/0-hosts`

```ini
[server]
demo_1.example.com dc="pri"
demo_2.example.com dc="sec"
demo_3.example.com dc="pri"
```

`inventory/1-constructed.yml`

```yaml
---
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
strict: False
groups:
    primary: dc == 'pri'
    secondary: dc == 'sec'
```

As you can see the global resulting inventoy will have the same groups as above

```
$ ansible-inventory -i inventory/ --list
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "demo_1.example.com": {
                "dc": "pri"
            },
            "demo_2.example.com": {
                "dc": "sec"
            },
            "demo_3.example.com": {
                "dc": "pri"
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "primary",
            "secondary",
            "servers",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "primary": {
        "hosts": [
            "demo_1.example.com",
            "demo_3.example.com"
        ]
    },
    "secondary": {
        "hosts": [
            "demo_2.example.com"
        ]
    },
    "servers": {
        "hosts": [
            "demo_1.example.com",
            "demo_2.example.com",
            "demo_3.example.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

So you can target them exactly as I described earlier.

Comment: A hearty AMEN.  I've seen so many problems caused by a badly designed inventory.

Comment: Also prefere `group_vars` yaml file for groups, I find it easier to manager and more powerful as you can a richer variables structures.

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Run a playbook over the servers with `dc="pri"`"***

A: Use the inventory plugin *constructed* and create inventory groups by the value of the variable. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t inventory ansible.builtin.constructed
```

**In your case, use *`keyed_groups`* instead of just *`groups`*. You don't have to specify the values of the variable. The names of the created groups will be automatically constructed by using the values of the variable.**

For example, the tree below for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory
│   ├── 01-hosts
│   └── 02-constructed.yml
└── pb.yml

1 directory, 4 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/inventory
stdout_callback = yaml
```

Create the inventory

```ini
shell> cat inventory/01-hosts 
[server]
demo_1.example.com dc="pri"
demo_2.example.com dc="sec"
demo_3.example.com dc="pri"
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yml 
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
keyed_groups:
  - key: dc
    prefix: dc
    default_value: pool
```

and test it. Two new groups *dc_pri* and *dc_sec* will be created

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    dc_pri:
      hosts:
        demo_1.example.com:
          dc: pri
        demo_3.example.com:
          dc: pri
    dc_sec:
      hosts:
        demo_2.example.com:
          dc: sec
    server:
      hosts:
        demo_1.example.com: {}
        demo_2.example.com: {}
        demo_3.example.com: {}
    ungrouped: {}
```

Use the groups. For example, in the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --limit dc_pri

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [demo_1.example.com] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - demo_1.example.com
  - demo_3.example.com

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
demo_1.example.com: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Nice discorvery, I didn't know about this new constructed plugin.

Comment: See all of them `shell> ansible-doc -t inventory -l`

Answer (score 0):

I receive an parsing error when executing the inventory... seems the plugin is not loaded?
0-inventory.yaml

```
[app_server]
demo_1.example.com dc="pri"
demo_2.example.com dc="sec"
demo_3.example.com dc="pri"
```

1-constructed.yaml

```
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
strict: False
groups:
primary: dc == 'pri'
secondary: dc == 'sec'
```

tree

```
.
├── inventory
│   ├── 0-hosts
│   └── 1-constructed.yaml
├── pb_filter.yaml
└── task1.yaml
```

execution outcome

```
$ ansible-inventory -i inventory/ --list
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
/mnt/c/Users/rcarb/Documents/GitHub/Ansible/Ansible_test/Ansible_filter_inventory/inventory/1-constructed.yaml with
script plugin: problem running
/mnt/c/Users/rcarb/Documents/GitHub/Ansible/Ansible_test/Ansible_filter_inventory/inventory/1-constructed.yaml --list
([Errno 8] Exec format error:
'/mnt/c/Users/rcarb/Documents/GitHub/Ansible/Ansible_test/Ansible_filter_inventory/inventory/1-constructed.yaml')
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
/mnt/c/Users/rcarb/Documents/GitHub/Ansible/Ansible_test/Ansible_filter_inventory/inventory/1-constructed.yaml with
auto plugin: Invalid value "ansible.builtin.constructed" for configuration option "plugin_type: inventory plugin:
ansible_collections.ansible.builtin.plugins.inventory.constructed setting: plugin ", valid values are: ['constructed']
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
/mnt/c/Users/rcarb/Documents/GitHub/Ansible/Ansible_test/Ansible_filter_inventory/inventory/1-constructed.yaml with
yaml plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
/mnt/c/Users/rcarb/Documents/GitHub/Ansible/Ansible_test/Ansible_filter_inventory/inventory/1-constructed.yaml with ini
plugin: Invalid host pattern '---' supplied, '---' is normally a sign this is a YAML file.
[WARNING]: Unable to parse
/mnt/c/Users/rcarb/Documents/GitHub/Ansible/Ansible_test/Ansible_filter_inventory/inventory/1-constructed.yaml as an
inventory source
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "demo_1.example.com": {
                "dc": "pri"
            },
            "demo_2.example.com": {
                "dc": "sec"
            },
            "demo_3.example.com": {
                "dc": "pri"
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "app_server",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "app_server": {
        "hosts": [
            "demo_1.example.com",
            "demo_2.example.com",
            "demo_3.example.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

Any idea about why is failing to parse the inventory file?
Best regards